# Anylogic do not give the value of a variable

Tags: function, variable-assignment, anylogic, agent-based-modeling, statechart

I am a beginner and I am simulating a single model. However, the functions I defined are not working. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u10mo.jpg)
TimeTask is a function of CurrentTask and the LearningTime is a function of AgentA. CompletionTime = LearningTime(Agent) + TimeTask(CurrentTask). Under some condition, AgentA can get information from AgentB with probability1 or R with 1-probability1. Could you please help me in this matter? I can get the correct output from CurrentTask variable. However, the final value of CompletionTime is zero.

- I think some of my functions defined based on the variables are not working correctly.
- I also checked the Java code and understood there is one more {} in the code that I do not know it can affect the results or not.
- I also think I do not select a correct place for them.

Comment: We can't help you with the information given

Comment: yes, happy to help but this is like asking "my car does not start, here is a picture of it parking in the parking lot" :) You need to help us help you. Here are some tips on asking good questions to get help fast: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow